# Docker compose - python: can't open file - "No such file or directory" on Windows

Tags: python, windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm a beginner in working with docker especially docker compose.I am working on a Windows machine (Windows 8.1 single language) so I am using Docker Toolbox.
All of my files are present in the Windows machine at path- E:\xyz\docker

Following my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  tweet_collector:
    build: tweet_collector/
    volumes:
    - ./tweet_collector/:/app
  etl_job:
    build: etl_job/
    volumes:
    - ./etl_job/:/app2
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - "27021:27017"
  postgresdb:
    image: postgres
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=admin
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    - POSTGRES_DB=twitter_database
    ports:
    - "5554:5432"
  slack_bot:
    build: slack_bot/
    volumes:
    - ./slack_bot/:/app3
```

And my Dockerfile 1:

```sh
FROM python:3.6-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","get_tweets_for_mongo.py"]
```

my Dockerfile 2:

```sh
FROM python:3.6-slim
WORKDIR /app3
ADD . /app3
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "slack_bot.py"]
```

And my Dockerfile 3 -

```sh
FROM python:3.6-slim
WORKDIR /app2
ADD . /app2
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "scheduler.py"]
```

I am running my docker-compose.yml from E:\xyz\docker from my windows machine.
But I am getting the below error

```
slack_bot_1        | python: can't open file 'slack_bot.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
data-pipeline-twitter-master_slack_bot_1 exited with code 2
tweet_collector_1  | python: can't open file 'get_tweets_for_mongo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
data-pipeline-twitter-master_tweet_collector_1 exited with code 2
etl_job_1          | python: can't open file 'scheduler.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
data-pipeline-twitter-master_etl_job_1 exited with code 2
postgresdb_1       | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error, any suggestions on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], which doesn't need five services in particular.

Comment: The `volumes:` blocks shouldn't be necessary, and hide the code in the image build.  Does deleting these blocks help things start up?

Comment: Can you please share the current directory structure with the `docker-compose.yml`, all the Dockerfiles and the scripts?

Comment: The current directory structure and docker-compose.yml and all Dockerfiles and scripts can be found at -

https://github.com/vbelz/Data-pipeline-twitter

Comment: Even after deleting the volumn: blocks it is not working.